# Policy for empty tags

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

Is there a policy regarding tags without wikis/guidance?

e.g.: [Wiki for SO's uint tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/uint/info) is empty and `UINT` might refer to multiple entities (and is vague).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can suggest edits to clarify what they should be used for ("propose tag info" button at the bottom of the page you linked.)

If a tag is being used *incorrectly*, or otherwise needs special attention, you can ask a question on the site's meta (in this case [Meta Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com)) detailing the issue you see with the tag. If applicable, include the  course of action you think should be taken in dealing with it.